# Transmission won't start

Tags: transmission

When I launch transmission from Unity it won't start the first time. The second time I launch it, it takes a couple of minutes to start.
I tried to launch it from the terminal and I got this message, "(transmission-gtk:9225): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: Timeout was reached"

I already tried reinstalling it, but it didn't work.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Do you have any unstable repos in your sources.list. Apparently, this error arises due to a bug in the Glib unstable branch

Comment: Yes, as a matter of fact, I do.